# Changing Sites Language results in "Unexpected Error"

Tags: error, language

Using SharePoint Foundation....  I installed the Win Server 08 R2 language packs and SharePoint Foundation Beta language packs.  I changed my english language to Spanish on the SharePoint site and now i get "Unexpected Error" on all sharepoint pages.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft released the RTM Language packs  about a week ago and I have not had any issues since.

[Language packs for SharePoint 2010 download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=646e311a-aaf3-4d30-b03c-2f3c70d19a22&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the site by logging in with a different admin account, going to site actions > site sttings > language settings > unchecked Spanish and clicked OK.

This does not solve the functionality issue of being able to change a site's language on the fly however.

Any follow up is appreciated.

Comment: I also get the same error creating a new sub site in Spanish...

Comment: I assume you have a good reason, but why mess around with the potentially flakey beta when the RTM version is available?

Comment: Beta language packs are the only language packs available at the moment.  We're using the RTM Foundation bits

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error on RTM and Russian LP for Sharepoint Foundation... You can open site without using another account - just clean cookies in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Server Product Version Install Status 
 RA-IIS01 Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010   Installed 
 RA-IIS01  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 
 14.0.4763.1000 Installed 
 RA-IIS01  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack 
 14.0.4763.1000 Installed 
 RA-IIS01  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Core 
 14.0.4763.1000 Installed 
 RA-IIS01 SharePoint Foundation 2010 Language Pack - Russian/русский   Installed 
 RA-IIS01  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1049 Lang Pack 
 14.0.4536.1000 Installed 
 RA-IIS01  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1049 Lang Pack Core 
 14.0.4536.1000 Installed

We are using RTM as you can see. RTM Language pack released more 2 weeks ago...

Comment: Does anybody know how to get not localized error from .Net? My site generate errors in russian language, but I want see it in english.

Comment: Look's fun, but sharkmu25 rights! I've try download LP again and get newer version. After installing it error has been gone.
Final version of LP is 14.0.4763.1000, look's like MS upload wrong version in first days.